# My Gravatar won't change

Tags: support, gravatar

I changed my [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) a couple of weeks ago through my profile options on this site. Despite clearing my cache and trying alternative browsers (Firefox, Chrome) and computers (Windows and Linux), the new one stubbornly refuses to show up on this and associated sites.

The test option on the Gravatar page shows the right one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha - simple one - just spotted it as I was ticking the notification option when finishing my question!

1) Superuser registration had my email address as xxxxx@gmail.com

2) Gravatar registration was xxxxx@googlemail.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it back and then change it to the one that you want your delete it from Gravtar and then upload it back again.